# AngularJS ng-view not loading js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my AngularJS app. I'm trying to use a JavaScript of a bootstrap template inside of a ng-view, but is not working.
When I use this JavaScript in my index works great, but not inside of any view.

This is a part of my index.html:

```
    <!-- Breadcrumb -->

    <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Easing - Requirred for Lightbox + Pie Charts-->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Form Related -->
    <script src="js/select.min.js"></script> <!-- Custom Select -->
    <script src="js/chosen.min.js"></script> <!-- Custom Multi Select -->
    <script src="js/datetimepicker.min.js"></script> <!-- Date & Time Picker -->
    <script src="js/colorpicker.min.js"></script> <!-- Color Picker -->
    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->
```

When I use some of the features of any of the form related scripts inside of a ng-view don't work.

How can I use this scripts inside my ng-views?? I've tried to load the scripts inside the ng-views but still doesn't work.

Comment: just a shot - did You try to load those files before ng-view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to see from your code snippet, but have you tried loading jquery before angularjs file ? Angular works with jqLite and if your not loaded jQuery before angularjs file angular tries to load it with jqLite.

But, it is preffered to convert your jquery plugins to a directive in order for them work properly in your angular project.

Comment: Thanks!! that solved my problem. Loading the scripts in the correct order works. Anyway, I can't convert the external scripts in directives, too much work. Those scripts are only for the look & feel and came with the bootstrap theme.

Comment: Works but now my other ng-view fails to load content from my database